# Limitation for simultaneous aac tracks on iPad

Tags: ipad, aac

How many aac tracks can I play simultaneously, using 100% of iPad cpu? Apple documentation says that only first one will be decoded on hardware, other will be decoded in software mode, but there is no information if this decoding will be costly or not.

Comment: don't know much iPad but I guess much more than you will ever encounter with